# How to remove all comments in a HTML String

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have a `String` which has comments within `<! -->` ie `<!comment1-->`.
I want to remove all of these.

What would be the RE for this?

I tried:

```
replaceAll("\\<!.*?\\-\\-\\>", "");
```

But it didn't work.
i tried looping and replacing and it works but i am looking for a regular expression

I had already tried the html.fromHtml as mentioned in that ink and its not working. For that i have another question raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433879/android-placing-html-content-in-textview?noredirect=1#comment52733171_32433879)

eg string below

```
<style> <!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face  {font-family:"Cambria Math";    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;} @font-face       {font-family:Calibri;   panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} @font-face      {font-family:Tahoma;    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;} @font-face      {font-family:Webdings;  panose-1:5 3 1 2 1 5 9 6 7 3;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal         {margin:0in;    margin-bottom:.0001pt;  font-size:11.0pt;       font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink    {mso-style-priority:99;         color:#0563C1;  text-decoration:underline;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed        {mso-style-priority:99;         color:#954F72;  text-decoration:underline;} span.EmailStyle17   {mso-style-type:personal-compose;       font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;       color:windowtext;} .MsoChpDefault       {mso-style-type:export-only;    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} @page WordSection1   {size:8.5in 11.0in;     margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;} div.WordSection1       {page:WordSection1;} --></style>
```

Comment: Have you tried `replaceAll("<!--(.*?)-->", "");` ?

Comment: [This does'nt work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7389663/2413972)

Comment: no . that didnt work

Comment: See [this](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/regex-pattern-to-strip-html-comments-but-leave-conditonals/6476/9) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132488/regex-to-remove-conditional-comments)

Comment: Try [`(?s)<!\\b.*?-->`](https://regex101.com/r/gB1jM1/1) or please post what texts you are trying to match exactly.

Comment: i have added my string

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you receive returned value from `String.replaceAll`.

```
String html = "abcde<!--comment1-->\n"
        + "<p>abcdefghi<!--comment2-->jkl</p>\n"
        + "<p>abcdefghi<span>jklm<!--comment3-->nopq</span>rs</p>\n";

String commentsRemoved = html.replaceAll("<!--.*?-->", "");

System.out.println(html);
System.out.println(commentsRemoved);
```

Comment: pretty valid html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title><!-- aaa</title></head><body><a href="">aaaa--></a><script >window.title = "-->";</script>-->aaaa aaaa<!-- aaaa   //--> <script >window.title = "-->";</script></body></html>`

Comment: This answer works great.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Try this
 string ss = "<b><i>The tag is about to be removed</i></b>";
    Regex regex = new Regex("\\<[^\\>]*\\>");
    Response.Write(String.Format("<b>Before:</b>{0}", ss)); // HTML Text
    Response.Write("<br/>");
    ss = regex.Replace(ss, String.Empty);
    Response.Write(String.Format("<b>After:</b>{0}", ss));// Plain Text as a  OUTPUT
```

Comment: that removes all the tags and text looses the format . I want only the comments to be removed and then i am using fromHtml . I ha dtried this

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136704/Remove-all-the-HTML-tags-and-display-a-plain-text   check this link